# Interpretar símbolos especiales en Python (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py

estoy programando un bot para discord, y en un comando en específico se encarga de hacer scraping de acuerdo a la palabra que el usuario introduce junto con el comando !rankr (por ejemplo: !rankr jugador1). Hasta ahora todo funciona bien, el problema comienza cuando el usuario busca una palabra con un caracter especial como "Ø" por ejemplo. Cuando eso pasa, inmediatamente me lanza error de encoding porque el codigo ascii no puede interpretar dicho símbolo. Cómo puedo hacer para que mi comando interprete dichos símbolos y haga la busqueda correspondiente?

Éste  es mi código actual:

```
@bot.command(name="rankr")
async def rankr(ctx, arg):
    #Diccionaro de simbologías:
    o = u'\xd8'
    
    html = urlopen('http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=' + arg)
    url = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=" + arg
    legionurl = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/legion/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=" + arg + "&search=true&region=#ranking"
```

Donde "arg" es la palabra escrita por el cliente junto con el comando.

Edit: Al hacer estos cambios me lanza otro error donde dice que el objeto de tipo 'int' no tiene len():

```
html = urlopen('http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=' + quote(entrada))
    url = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=" + quote(entrada)
    legionurl = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/legion/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=" + quote(entrada) + "&search=true&region=#ranking"
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Recuerda poner un ejemplo [**mínimo**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y la traza completa del error en la pregunta. Como falla en la primer llamada a *urlopen* no creo que el código que sigue sea relevante para la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Las urls que recibe *urlopen* deben ser convertibles a la codificación ASCII.
Como "Ø" es un símbolo que no puede ser representado en esa codificación, *urlopen*
tira una excepción *UnicodeEncodeError* al intentar convertirlo.

Para solucionarlo deberías escapar los símbolos conflictivos con *urllib.parse.quote*.
Por ejemplo:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen

entrada = "Ø"

response = urlopen("https://httpbin.org/get?q=" + quote(entrada))

print(response.getcode())
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no quiero evadir dichos símbolos, sino que literalmente me haga la búsqueda utilizandolos, la página donde se realiza la búsqueda si reconoce tales caracteres. Además, no todo el tiempo el usuario busca palabras con caracteres especiales.

Comment: Creo que debería funcionar igual, ya que el servidor lo que hace es el proceso contrario (para obtener los simbolos originales) y hacer la busqueda.

Comment: Aun no comprendo del todo como emplearlo directamente en mi ejemplo, anexé lo que hice con lo que tu me pusiste al post principal. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Al fin pude descifrar como hacerlo. Básicamente tuve que transformar a bytes la variable arg:

```
arg = bytes(arg,'utf-8')
```

y después cuando quiera usarla para un request, especificar que tiene que hacer un decode a 'utf-8':

```
url = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=" + arg.decode('utf-8')
```

De esta manera es que logré hacerlo, desconozco si sea la mejor forma pero en definitiva me funcionó.